# scrolling iframe with parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe

How to scroll the parent window together with scrolling the iframe.I mean to say if someone scroll the iframe it should scroll the parent window as well. I am thinking to achieve this by javascript. The origins are the same.

Comment: Do the parent document and the iframe share the same origin?

Comment: @Nitzan yes same origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your two documents share the same origin you are not restricted by the same origin policy, meaning that you can just call from javascript in one document to javascript in the other document.

A simple example:

**The parent `index.html`**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function handleMessage(msg) {
                console.log("message from iframe: ", msg);
            }

            function sendMessage() {
                let msg = {
                    value: document.getElementById("message").value
                }

                document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">send message to parent</button>
        <br/><br/>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The `iframe.html`**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function handleMessage(msg) {
                console.log("message from parent: ", msg);
            }

            function sendMessage() {
                let msg = {
                    value: document.getElementById("message").value
                }

                parent.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">send message to parent</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now that you know how to call js methods from one document to the other, it should be simple enough to catch scrolling events in one and then let the other know about the scroll delta.

Comment: thanks but i am really new to javascript can you provide with scrolling example.

Comment: This site isn't a place to ask people to write your code for you. You should ask questions after you've tried to make things work yourself but haven't figured out how. Then when you ask a question you are expected to include what you've tried so far and how it failed. How else do you expect to learn js? You should start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll